# How to remove a OpenLDAP ACL?

Tags: openldap

I accidentally created a bad ACL. I’m aware of the manner in which to update the ACL but the truth is I don’t need it any more. When updating it looks like I accidentally created new ACLs vs modifying so I have a ton of ACLs I don’t need. Basically I am not able to figure out the ldif manner in which to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `sudo ldapmodify  -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f aclrm.ldif`
vs `sudo ldapdelete  -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f aclrm.ldif`

For whatever reason `ldapdelete` command does not work in this context and you have to use `ldapmodify`

Here are the contents of my ldif file

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess
olcAccess: {4}
```

Comment: `ldapdelete` is for deleting whole entries, not attributes.